# Windows 8: Fast creation of many user accounts

Tags: windows, windows-8, user-accounts, administrator

When logging into a newly created account for the first time, one is taken on a 'tour' while Windows is 'setting up some stuff'. This takes several minutes. Without this process the user folder C:\Users is not created. How can I speed up or skip this step?

I have to create dozens of user accounts on a PC with Windows 8 and then copy specific files into the user folder C:\Users\UsernameXXX\ of each account. The data copying step can quickly be done while logged into an administrator account. However, first I need to create all these accounts and then log into each single one, waiting for the 'setup' process to pass by, then log into the next user account, wait again... Surely, there must be a fast way to do this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: It sounds like you need a domain, and just setup the default user profile, to include certain files.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, thanks for your answer. No, I dont want to setup a domain and I dont want to include certain files. All I want is to create user accounts that can be used immediately without Windows "setting up" those identical accounts for several minutes. I will update the question to make it more clear.